# Generate random falling objects in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, loops

I want to create a set of random objects to fall down the stage in a loop.

So far I have created a test object to fall at a random x coordinate. I am having trouble working out how to loop the falling function so multiple instances of the object continuously fall.

```
var randomX:Number = Math.random() * 800;

test_mc.x = randomX;
test_mc.y = 0;

var speed:Number = 10;

test_mc.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown);

function moveDown(e:Event):void
{
 e.target.y += speed; 

 if(e.target.y >= 480)
 {
      test_mc.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

refer my a falling snow effect code.

The starting position of the snow is all random, almost same effect that real snow falling circumstance. If you run You'll be amazed.

The Snow is My Custom MovieClip (white circle shape, width 15, height 15)

here is my demo: [SnowEffect](http://www.swfcabin.com/open/1344529578)

here is my source: [SnowEffect Down](http://www.datafilehost.com/download-be9b2147.html)

```
this.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onEnter );

function onEnter( e: Event ):void {

    var s: Snow = new Snow();
    s.x=550*Math.random();
    s.y=-20;
    s.width=s.height=1+9*Math.random();// 1 ~ 9

    s.xSpeed=-2+4*Math.random();// -2 ~ 2
    s.ySpeed=1+4*Math.random();// 1 ~ 5

    s.at = -0.001 -0.001*Math.random();
    s.vt = 0;
    this.addChild( s );

    s.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onSnowEnter );
}

function onSnowEnter( e: Event ):void {
    var s:Snow=e.currentTarget as Snow;
    s.x+=s.xSpeed;
    s.y+=s.ySpeed;


    if (s.y>=480) {
        s.addEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onMeltingEnter );
    }
}

function onMeltingEnter( e: Event ): void {
    var s:Snow=e.currentTarget as Snow;
    this.addChild( s );
    s.removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onSnowEnter );
    s.vt += s.at;
    s.alpha += s.vt;
    if ( s.alpha <=0){
        s.removeEventListener( Event.ENTER_FRAME, onMeltingEnter );
        this.removeChild( s );
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a bunch of objects, add them to an array and then loop through the array:

```
var numOfObjects:int = 10;
var fallingObjectArray:Array = [];
var speed:Number = 10;

// Add 10 falling objects to the display and to the array
for(var i:int = 0; i < numOfObjects; i++) {
   var fallingObject:Sprite = new Sprite();
   fallingObject.graphics.beginFill(0xFF0000);
   fallingObject.graphics.drawCircle(0, 0, 15);
   fallingObject.graphics.endFill();
   addChild(fallingObject);
   fallingObject.x = Math.random() * stage.stageWidth;
   fallingObjectArray.push(fallingObject);
}

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown);

function moveDown(e:Event):void
{    
   // Go through all the objects in the array and move them down
   for each(var fallingObject in fallingObjectArray) {
      fallingObject.y += speed;
      // If the object is past the screen height, remove it from display and array
      if(fallingObject.y+fallingObject.height >= stage.stageHeight) {
         removeChild(fallingObject);
         fallingObjectArray.splice(fallingObjectArray.indexOf(fallingObject), 1);
      }
   }
   // Once all objects have fallen off the screen, remove the listener
   if(fallingObjectArray.length <= 0) {
      removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, moveDown);
   }
}
```

The code above is just using red circles - you will have to use whatever image you have instead (unless you like red circles...).